# attributes html controls

Tags: c#, html, controls

```
<td class="ui-widget-header gvHeader ui-helper-hidden" style="width: 17%" runat="server" id="tdPack">
Pack :
</td>
```

I want to remove the class 'ui-helper-hidden' using C# code. How ?

Comment: Please add way more context about what you are doing and where (on the server? In a client program? Where does the HTML come from?)

Comment: I would like to remove the class ( only the 'ui-helper-hidden') using C# Code.

Answer (score 0):

assuming several things due to lack of details, you might try:

```
tdPack.CssClass = tdPack.CssClass.Replace("ui-widget-header", String.Empty);
```

or if that is `HtmlTableCell` than:

```
tdPack.Attributes["class"] =
       Attributes["class"].Replace("ui-widget-header", String.Empty);
```

Comment: here is a more explicit example with some helper methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445967/c-best-way-to-change-css-classes-from-code

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should retag your question!
then: provide more information!
then: i assume that `ui-helper-hidden` is added by a plugin - this means, that this is not the rendered source rather the computed sourced - you will not be able to change the `class`-attribute...
the crucial question: do you know the difference between server- and client-side?

you will have to use jquery or any other javascript (lib), to do sth like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cell = $('#yourControlId);
    // or
    var $cell = $('.ui-helper-hidden');
    $cell.removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');
});
```

another crucial question here:
if this is your code, why don't you leave the unwanted `ui-helper-hidden`-class out? your supported code shows, that you have the control over the code and there's no plugin or sth alike involved ...