# Javascript onClick change border of image on ASP Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, image

I have an ASP page that has 5 ASP ImageButtons. The images can be clicked and then a few things happen in the code behind. I also want the images to be outlined with a border when the user clicks it so they know that one has been selected. I am using javascript to accomplish the outline with a border. But my problem is that the border applies then the page refreshed and the border is gone. I know that the Imagebuttons are causing a post back, but how can I keep my ImageButtons outline after the postback?

Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function chnageborder(imageid) 
    {
        document.getElementById(imageid).style.border = "solid 2px #2F74D0";
    }
</script>
```

ASP Imagebutton:

```
<asp:ImageButton 
            ID="Image1" runat="server" 
            style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin-right: 5px;" OnClick="Image1_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:chnageborder('Image1'); return true;"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle that in the server side. Basically the style can be applied in the postback of the particular image button click event.

```
void Image1_Click()
{
Image1.Styles.Add("border" , "solid 2px #2F74D0");

//And you need to revert the styles of the other buttons if they already have the selected style

Image2.Style["border"] = "";
.
.
Image5.Style["border"] = "";

}
```

Or if you want to do it in a more cleaner way, you can adopt one css class and apply that class in the code behind as one answer suggest below. You might need another css class to have the un-selected style and apply that same as above to make them look normal.

Answer (score 1):

Define your border within a class selector in CSS, then apply that class to your image in the code-behind on PostBack.

**CSS**

```
.selected { border: 2px solid  #2F74D0};
```

**C#**

```
Image1.CssClass = "selected";
```

It's worth noting that this is a basic example and will overwrite any existing classes.  If you want to add to the class collection, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445967/c-best-way-to-change-css-classes-from-code) provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   void Image1_Click()
     {
     Image1.Attributes.Add("Style" , "Border:solid 2px #2F74D0");       
     }
```