# Highlight Row - Link button Clicked in RAD grid

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with an asp Link Button. I want to highlight the row whose link button has been clicked.

Following is the code from my grid:

```
<rad:GridTemplateColumn                                     
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditRole" runat="server" Text="View Teams" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Roleid") %>' OnClick="Editrole_Click">
         </asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
</rad:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Regards,
Rmn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the html generated by the grid, then you can make a css class .highlighted and a jQuery event like this:

```
$("#id_of_button").click(function(){
    $("#id_of_row").addClass("highlighted");
});
```

Simple solution. (if you can show the generated html, I can give more specific help)

**Edit:**

If `View Leaders` is you link button:

```
$("[id$=LinkViewTeam]").click(function(){
    $(this).parent.parent.addClass("highlighted");
});
```

Comment: can you suggest something in Javascript instead of Jquery ?

Comment: Do you want this code?   <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_cphMain_rgFacility_ctl00__4"> 
 <td style="width:10%;">
               <a id="ctl00_cphMain_rgFacility_ctl00_ctl08_LinkViewTeam" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$rgFacility$ctl00$ctl08$lnkEditRole','')">View Leaders
  </a>
         </td>

Comment: Also, I am already using the onclick event at serverside. If you can suggest anything at server-side, that too will be helpful.

Comment: view [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445967/c-sharp-best-way-to-change-css-classes-from-code) if you want to change the css server-side